# Java Collections.sort doesn't call compare method

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I've read all answers etc, but non of them solved my problem.

I have basic function to sort list of custom object array by String InvoiceNumber.

```
List<Invoice> invoiceList = new ArrayList<>();

...
// invoiceList filled here
...

Collections.sort(invoiceList, new Comparator<Invoice>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Invoice o1, Invoice o2)
    {
           return o1.InvoiceNumber.compareTo(o2.InvoiceNumber);
    }
});
```

Some part of Invoice class.

```
public class Invoice extends AttributeContainer
implements KvmSerializable,android.os.Parcelable, Comparable
{

public String CustomerId;

public String InvoiceNumber;
```

[image: Picture of more code. Yea.]

However, it never calls compare method.

I'm using android studio with latest libraries. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: How are you sure it never calls it?

Comment: What is the type of InvoiceNumber?

Comment: Have you added print statements to the method?  Is the list empty?

Comment: When I debug, it never runs maszter. Yes, it is Jake. Of course list is not empty Jacob.

Comment: please post Invoice.class and InvoiceNumber.class

Comment: Sorry invoice number is String. @JiriS

Comment: Post the class / method which utilizes this comparator. We cannot determine why it's not being called (or if it's not even being called for that matter) with the little snippet of code you've posted.

Comment: Are you sure `invoiceList` has at least 2 elements?

Comment: It's confusing to see `InvoiceNumber` spelled like a type name but used like a member variable. Which is it?

Comment: It's auto generated class @LewBloch. It's member variable.

Comment: Debugger says it has 5 @AndyTurner.

Comment: Note that `Invoice` shouldn't implement `Comparable`, but rather `Comparable<Invoice>`. And you don't *really* need to implement `Comparable<Invoice>` (or `Comparable`) if you're providing a `Comparator`; but you can, if you so desire.

Comment: Instead of "I will pretend that the Internet is magic and not bother telling them", tell the type of the `invoiceList` variable.

Comment: If I were you, while I've got that debugger running, I'd step into `Collections.sort()` just to see what happens inside. It's a lot simpler than asking a bunch of people on the internet to try to guess randomly.

Comment: Have you tried figuring out whether or not your switch statement executes "Invoice Number"? Maybe you mispelled "Invoice Number" or there's a case sensitivity issue? It's hard to say because you're not giving us enough code to work with. Show us the ENTIRE switch statement where you're trying to execute this comparator and show us your input into the switch statement.

Comment: @MmtBkn, is that an in-house code generator creating a variable spelled `InvoiceNumber`? Industry-standard tools usually adhere to the naming conventions. If it's an in-house tool I advise submitting a trouble ticket to repair that mistake.

Comment: Sorry this is one of my first question @DwB it's List<Invoice>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, it never calls compare method.

The only time that the `compare(...)` method would not be called is if your list has 0 or 1 items in it.  Probably this is a debugging problem with Android and the `compare(...)` *is* being called but maybe the breakpoint is being skipped.  Putting some sort of log messages inside of the method will confirm this.

I suspect that your problem is here:

```
public String InvoiceNumber;
```

First of all the field name should be `invoiceNumber` with a starting lowercase letter.  Also it probably should *not* be public for [data hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) reasons.

But I suspect that real problem is with `String` comparisons of numbers.  For example if you have the following invoice-number strings in your entities:

```
1
2
3
10
11
20
25
114
201
```

Then these will sort like:

```
1
10
11
114
2
20
25
201
3
```

That's how the `String.compare(...)` method would sort it because the string `"3"` is greater than the string `"201"`.  If you want them to be sorted as numbers then you should make the `invoiceNumber` field be an `int` or `long`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating anonymous class for the `sort` method. Try to extract your `Comparator` class and you'll be able to debug.